# Can we predict features from labels in machine learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science, artificial-intelligence

Given a dataset with 100 observations and 3 features plus one label(regression). we train the model with 100 * 4(3 features + 1 label) data. Now can we predict the features when the label is given as input.
For eg:

```
f1 f2 f3 Label
2  2  3  12.5
3  6  5  3.8
6  5  4  9.2
..........
..........
..........
..........
```

now the question is to predict f1, f2 and f3 when label is given ( if label=6.7 then predict f1,f2,f3).

It would be of great help if any suggestion or resources is provided.

Comment: Please ask in Cross Validated.

Comment: maybe it can be better to ask on similar portals: [DataScience](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)  or [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have a ML model, which takes one input variable and should predict three output variables. if that is the case, then [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/deep-learning-models-for-multi-output-regression/) tutorial will help you.

Basically a model in Keras could look like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(20, input_dim=1, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
```

The link provides even more insights on how to properly evaluate this network, since you have a rather small dataset of 100 observations.